# Making a block of "unsafe" code "safe"

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I have this unsafe code that I need to make safe so it can execute. I know about the `fixed` block, but I don't know how to implement it:

```
    private static unsafe void PrintHex(byte* data, uint len)
    {
        uint ctr;
        string sep;

        if (len > 64)
        {
            len = 64;
        }

        for (ctr = 0; ctr < len; ctr++)
        {
            if (((ctr & 7) == 0) && (ctr != 0))
            {
                sep = "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                sep = "";
            }
            Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}{1:X}", sep, data[ctr]);
        }

        Console.Error.WriteLine("\n\n");

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to make this safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the responsibility of the calling code to 'fix' or 'pin' the pointer before calling your method, as in this example from the MSDN page for [`fixed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f58wzh21%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

```
class Point
{ 
    public int x, y; 
}

class FixedTest 
{
    // Unsafe method: takes a pointer to an int.
    unsafe static void SquarePtrParam (int* p) 
    {
        *p *= *p;
    }

    unsafe static void Main() 
    {
        Point pt = new Point();
        pt.x = 5;
        pt.y = 6;

        // Pin pt in place:
        fixed (int* p = &pt.x) 
        {
            SquarePtrParam(p);
        }

        // pt now unpinned
        Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1}", pt.x, pt.y);
    }
}
```

> The fixed statement sets a pointer to a managed variable and "pins"
>   that variable during the execution of statement. Without fixed,
>   pointers to movable managed variables would be of little use since
>   garbage collection could relocate the variables unpredictably. The C#
>   compiler only lets you assign a pointer to a managed variable in a
>   fixed statement.

Answer (score 3):

> I have this unsafe code that I need to make safe so it can execute.

Any code which use a `byte*` (or any other pointer type), by definition, will always be "unsafe" code in C#.  There is no way to convert this to "safe" code without completely changing the API.

That being said, this could work on a managed byte array like so:

```
private static void PrintHex(byte[] data, uint len)
{
    uint ctr;
    string sep;

    if (len > 64)
    {
        len = 64;
    }

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < len && ctr < data.Length; ctr++)
    {
        if (((ctr & 7) == 0) && (ctr != 0))
        {
            sep = "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            sep = "";
        }
        Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}{1:X}", sep, data[ctr]);
    }

    Console.Error.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
```

This will work the same way off a "safe" managed array (`byte[]`).

Also - if "len" was just the array length, you can eliminate that argument entirely, as managed arrays include their length, unlike a pointer:

```
private static void PrintHex(byte[] data)
{
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 64 && ctr < data.Length; ctr++)
    {
        string sep;
        if (((ctr & 7) == 0) && (ctr != 0))
        {
            sep = "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            sep = "";
        }
        Console.Error.WriteLine("{0}{1:X}", sep, data[ctr]);
    }

    Console.Error.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
```